# Help simplifying a Makefile for multiple executables

Tags: c++, makefile

I have common code (e.g. `hello.cpp`) that is used by multiple executables.  I'm using a single Makefile to build it all:

```
EXE=app1.out app2.out
SRC=hello.cpp
OBJ=$(SRC:.cpp=.o)
SRC_MAIN=app1.cpp app2.cpp
OBJ_MAIN=$(SRC_MAIN:.cpp=.o)
all: $(EXE)    
app1.out: app1.o $(OBJ)
    g++ $< $(OBJ) -o $@    
app2.out: app2.o $(OBJ)
    g++ $< $(OBJ) -o $@    
.cpp.o:
    g++ -c $< -o $@    
clean:
    rm -f $(EXE) $(OBJ) $(OBJ_MAIN)
```

I'm not very happy about having a separate target for each executable -- the targets are essentially the same.  Is there any way to do this with one target for all executables?  I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
EXE=app1.out app2.out
SRC=hello.cpp
OBJ=$(SRC:.cpp=.o)
SRC_MAIN=app1.cpp app2.cpp
OBJ_MAIN=$(SRC_MAIN:.cpp=.o)
all: $(EXE)
.o.out: $(OBJ)
    g++ $< $(OBJ) -o $@
.cpp.o:
    g++ -c $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -f $(EXE) $(OBJ) $(OBJ_MAIN)
```

But I get a linking error:

```
misha@misha-desktop:~/cpp/stack$ make -f Makefile2
g++ -c app1.cpp -o app1.o
g++ app1.o hello.o -o app1.out
g++: hello.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [app1.out] Error 1
rm app1.o
```

For some reason it tries to build `app1.out` without building its dependency `hello.o`.  Can anyone explain why this doesn't work, and suggest something that does?

Here's the rest of the dummy code, just in case.

app1.cpp:

```
#include "hello.h"   
int
main(void)
{
    print_hello();
}
```

app2.cpp:

```
#include "hello.h"    
int
main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        print_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

hello.cpp:

```
#include "hello.h"    
#include <stdio.h>    
void
print_hello()
{
    printf("hello world!\n");
}
```

hello.h:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H
void
print_hello();
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are using old-style suffix rules.  From the make info:

> Suffix rules cannot have any prerequisites of their own.  If they
>    have any, they are treated as normal files with funny names, not as
>    suffix rules.  Thus, the rule:
>
> ```
>   .c.o: foo.h
>           $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
> ```
>
> tells how to make the file '.c.o' from the prerequisite file 'foo.h',
>    and is not at all like the pattern rule:
>
> ```
>   %.o: %.c foo.h
>           $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
> ```
>
> which tells how to make '.o' files from '.c' files, and makes all '.o'
>    files using this pattern rule also depend on 'foo.h'.

The solution is to use new-style pattern rules:

```
%.out: %.o $(OBJ)
    g++ $< $(OBJ) -o $@
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

(Also note that you don't need to define a .cpp to .o rule; `make` has a sensible default.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I use the .cpp to .o rule to provide custom `CPPFLAGS` to the compiler.  I didn't show them in the sample code because I was keeping things simple.  Will `make` defaults still include the "default" variable names (e.g. `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, etc)?

Comment: Yes, but `CPPFLAGS` is for the C pre-processor.  `CXXFLAGS` is for C++ flags.